# How to plot a graph in MATLAB using a vector of time values in hh:mm format

Tags: matlab, plot, epoch

I have a vector of time values in `hh:mm` format as well as a vector of values representing levels of activity.

For example:

```
x=[06:18, 07:58, 08:38, 09:18, 10:58];
y=[14, 28, 33, 68, 24];
```

Is it possible to plot a graph of `y vs. x` in Matlab?

If not, is there a way to display a vector of EPOCH time values as time in the format `hh:mm`, on the graph?

For example:

```
x= [1383260400, 1383261000, 1383261600, 1383262200, 1383262800];
y=[14, 28, 33, 68, 24];
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also change the [`TickLabels`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html). This does not require Time Series object

```
time={'06:18', '07:58', '08:38', '09:18', '10:58'};
data=[14, 28, 33, 68, 24];
plot(data)
set(gca,'XTickLabel', time)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is actually better suited for what I am doing

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
time={'06:18', '07:58', '08:38', '09:18', '10:58'};
data=[14, 28, 33, 68, 24];
ts = timeseries(data,time);
ts.TimeInfo.Format = 'HH:MM';
ts.TimeInfo.StartDate = '00:00';
plot(ts)
```

The time stamps must be in a cell array and apart from that it should be pretty self explanatory.

If you would like to plot more lines in the same plot and the same time stamps just use a matrix instead of a vector for the data:

```
data=[14, 28, 33, 68, 24; 7, 14, 35, 34, 12];
```

Comment: Hey,  if I wanted to plot more than one line on the same axis how would I do this?

Comment: Ohhh...Thank you so much